# Error creating bean with name 'processEngine' in Spring Boot and Activiti

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, activiti

I am new to Activiti and Spring Boot. I am following the [Getting started with Activiti and Spring Boot blog](https://spring.io/blog/2015/03/08/getting-started-with-activiti-and-spring-boot). So far I've only created a simple workflow with start event, store resume service task and end event. When I run the Spring boot app, it gives me an `Error creating bean with name 'processEngine'` exception. Following is my full exception log:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'runtimeServiceBean' defined in class path resource [org/activiti/spring/boot/DataSourceProcessEngineAutoConfiguration$DataSourceProcessEngineConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'runtimeServiceBean' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'processEngine': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/activiti/bpmn/constants/BpmnXMLConstants
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:767)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:508)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1127)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:846)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:863)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248)
    at com.test.myResume.MyResumeApplication.main(MyResumeApplication.java:15)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'processEngine': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/activiti/bpmn/constants/BpmnXMLConstants
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:178)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:101)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1647)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1216)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:257)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:273)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.addCandidateEntry(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1462)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1419)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1166)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:855)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:758)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/activiti/bpmn/constants/BpmnXMLConstants
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.cfg.DefaultBpmnParseFactory.createBpmnParse(DefaultBpmnParseFactory.java:25)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.parser.BpmnParser.createParse(BpmnParser.java:59)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.deployer.BpmnDeployer.deploy(BpmnDeployer.java:109)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.deploy.DeploymentManager.deploy(DeploymentManager.java:58)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.cmd.DeployCmd.execute(DeployCmd.java:106)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.cmd.DeployCmd.execute(DeployCmd.java:37)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandInvoker.execute(CommandInvoker.java:24)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContextInterceptor.execute(CommandContextInterceptor.java:57)
    at org.activiti.spring.SpringTransactionInterceptor$1.doInTransaction(SpringTransactionInterceptor.java:47)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140)
    at org.activiti.spring.SpringTransactionInterceptor.execute(SpringTransactionInterceptor.java:45)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.LogInterceptor.execute(LogInterceptor.java:31)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.cfg.CommandExecutorImpl.execute(CommandExecutorImpl.java:40)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.cfg.CommandExecutorImpl.execute(CommandExecutorImpl.java:35)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.RepositoryServiceImpl.deploy(RepositoryServiceImpl.java:78)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.repository.DeploymentBuilderImpl.deploy(DeploymentBuilderImpl.java:156)
    at org.activiti.spring.autodeployment.DefaultAutoDeploymentStrategy.deployResources(DefaultAutoDeploymentStrategy.java:64)
    at org.activiti.spring.SpringProcessEngineConfiguration.autoDeployResources(SpringProcessEngineConfiguration.java:111)
    at org.activiti.spring.SpringProcessEngineConfiguration.buildProcessEngine(SpringProcessEngineConfiguration.java:67)
    at org.activiti.spring.ProcessEngineFactoryBean.getObject(ProcessEngineFactoryBean.java:60)
    at org.activiti.spring.ProcessEngineFactoryBean.getObject(ProcessEngineFactoryBean.java:32)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:171)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.activiti.bpmn.constants.BpmnXMLConstants
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 64 more
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>myResume</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>myResume</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <activiti.version>5.19.0.2</activiti.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.activiti</groupId>
            <artifactId>activiti-spring-boot-starter-basic</artifactId>
            <version>${activiti.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.185</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

**hiringProcess.bpmn**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:activiti="http://activiti.org/bpmn" xmlns:bpmndi="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/DI" xmlns:omgdc="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DC" xmlns:omgdi="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DI" typeLanguage="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" expressionLanguage="http://www.w3.org/1999/XPath" targetNamespace="http://www.activiti.org/test">
  <process id="hiringProcess" name="Hiring process" isExecutable="true">
    <startEvent id="startevent1" name="Start"></startEvent>
    <serviceTask id="storeResume" name="Store Resume" activiti:expression="${resumeService.storeResume()}"></serviceTask>
    <sequenceFlow id="flow1" sourceRef="startevent1" targetRef="storeResume"></sequenceFlow>
    <endEvent id="endevent1" name="End"></endEvent>
    <sequenceFlow id="flow2" sourceRef="storeResume" targetRef="endevent1"></sequenceFlow>
  </process>
  <bpmndi:BPMNDiagram id="BPMNDiagram_hiringProcess">
    <bpmndi:BPMNPlane bpmnElement="hiringProcess" id="BPMNPlane_hiringProcess">
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="startevent1" id="BPMNShape_startevent1">
        <omgdc:Bounds height="35.0" width="35.0" x="160.0" y="170.0"></omgdc:Bounds>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="storeResume" id="BPMNShape_storeResume">
        <omgdc:Bounds height="55.0" width="105.0" x="240.0" y="160.0"></omgdc:Bounds>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="endevent1" id="BPMNShape_endevent1">
        <omgdc:Bounds height="35.0" width="35.0" x="390.0" y="170.0"></omgdc:Bounds>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement="flow1" id="BPMNEdge_flow1">
        <omgdi:waypoint x="195.0" y="187.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
        <omgdi:waypoint x="240.0" y="187.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement="flow2" id="BPMNEdge_flow2">
        <omgdi:waypoint x="345.0" y="187.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
        <omgdi:waypoint x="390.0" y="187.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
    </bpmndi:BPMNPlane>
  </bpmndi:BPMNDiagram>
</definitions>
```

**MyResumeApplication.java**

```
package com.test.myResume;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class MyResumeApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyResumeApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

I have tried both with and without the `CommandLineRunner init bean` as used in the above mentioned blog, but it gives me the same exception, so I believe the exception is not occurring because of it. The only difference I can find is that the blog uses spring boot v1.2.0.RELEASE and I'm using v2.1.0.RELEASE.
I also tried defining the process engine bean as stated in [this post](https://community.alfresco.com/thread/237730-newbie-using-activiti-6-and-springboot-201#comment-body-834695), but that doesn't seem to work either.

[This post](https://www.baeldung.com/activiti-process-engine) states to define a process engine in an XML file called `activiti.cfg.xml`, but I can find no such file. Do I need to create this file?

I'm having a hard time figuring this out. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you are using version 5.19.0.2 of Activiti? There are already versions 6 and 7 available. And the documentation-link you provided refers also to version 6. You can check out this page for documentation on the newer versions: https://www.activiti.org/documentation

Comment: looks like you are missing BpmnXMLConstants.class in your class path, are you sure you have in your pom file all the right dependencies?

Comment: @MuffinMICHI no I only used that version because the Getting Started guide used it. I tried using version 6.0.0 but now it gives me a different exception. `Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.activiti.spring.boot.SecurityAutoConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy`

Comment: @Rubenex I'm not sure about that but I've included all the dependencies mentioned in the Getting started guide. If I have to add BpmnXMLConstants.class, how and where do I do that?

Comment: make sure maven downloads all the jar files to your local repository, I just checked version 6.0.0 of activiti and it has the class you need.

Comment: Yes, that is quite an old version. Maybe you can check version 7 Beta1/Beta2/Beta3 which are based on top of Spring Boot 2.x: https://salaboy.com/2018/08/13/getting-started-with-activiti-core-7-0-0-beta1/